# Compare Between two value in different UOM

Tags: sql, powerbi

I try to build Report on Power Bi to show the comparison between Sales  achieved per items  and Targets  per items but the sales in many UOM and the Target in one UOM

How can i do it ?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `myMeasure= SUM(sales[qty])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach is:

- define a `Item_UOM` table which lists all possible UOMs for each Item, with a conversion factor to translate quantities in the "base" UOM. For instance for one item you may have "Pc." as your base UOM (factor = 1), and then "Box" (say factor = 12) as an alternative UOM.
- (Optimal): when you create a `Sales` record for 3 boxes you will store the UOM ("Box"), the quantity in boxes (3), and the quantity in pieces (3*12=36).
- (Suboptimal) if you cannot do the conversion when inserting the `Sales` record, you will need to do it while creating the report.